# htaccess redirect loop with "Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" is not allowed

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

i have htaccess for phprssreader, but it's make me can't login into admin area..
the hosting is in ipage, seems because `Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` is not allowed.

in another host like hawkhost it's working fine

here the htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

is there any solution for this, since i can't enable `Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` in panel or server.

Thank you

Comment: What's a link to the module you're using?  How did you install it?  Why do you need symlinks?  What error do you see when you try to access it using your current configuration?

Comment: Hi @ernie, that's default htaccess from the script(phprssreader)..
it just working fine in another common host.. but in ipage it's not working :(.

it give 500 error when 1st line enabled, when disabled it's working but can't login to admin.. seems can't read the GET variable

Comment: I don't know why it's need that symlinks. if there's solution to replace that functions it's good